# Ideal D Flip Flop

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop

I am a little confused about this homework question:

When assuming that an D Flip Flop is ideal, which of the situations are possible?

- While testing a circuit, the signal Q is observed changing as frequently as the signal c does.
- While testing a circuit, the signal i is observed changing more frequently than the signal c.
- While testing a circuit, the signal Q is observed changing more frequently than the signal c.
- While testing a circuit, the signal i is observed changing more frequently than the signal Q.
- While testing a circuit, the signal Q is observed changing less frequently than the signal c.

In all of these situations c is the clock, i is in the input for D, and Q is the output. My initial guess is that the last two choices are possible because Q is based off of the last change of i before the rising edge of the clock. Would my assumptions be correct?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is *almost* correct. The last two are indeed possible, because `Q` can only change when `i` changes, and `Q` changes at most half the speed of `c`. However, you are missing one case. As a hint, remember that `i` can do whatever it wants, regardless of `c` or `Q`.

Comment: Ah, alright.  So choices 2, 4, and 5 would be all of the possible cases than?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you.  Just to clarify it wouldn't be possible for Q to change as frequently as the clock, correct?

Comment: Yes, because Q only changes on the rising edge.